# Could not acess file: Array e syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, phpmailer, email

Estou usando PHPMailer para enviar um e-mail com anexo por uma formulário, meu código não tem erros, mas quando termino o formulário e pressiono enviar, retorna um erro mas que o e-mail foi enviado. Código:

```
   $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
   $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
   $message= $_REQUEST['message'];
   $message= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
   $message= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'" . PHP_EOL;
   $message= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
   $tapete=$_REQUEST['tapete'];
   $medidas=$_REQUEST['medidas'];
   $cliente=$_REQUEST['cliente'];
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
   $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = "mucapapipa.br@gmail.com";
   $mail->Password = "123Password";
   $mail->setFrom = ('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com');
   $mail->Subject   = 'Formulário FacilityCom';
   $mail->Body      = 'Tipo e marca: $tapete \nMedidas: $medidas \nCliente: $cliente\n $from';
   $mail->AddAddress= ('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com');
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $file_to_attach = $_FILES['file'];
   $filename=$_FILES['file'];
   $mail->AddAttachment($file_to_attach, $filename);
   $mail->Send();
```

O erro que recebo é:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/u746419992/public_html/index.php on line 42

Comment: $filename e $file_to_attach tem o mesmo valor. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @MucaP mas que campos, acho que você não entendeu, `error_reporting` é uma configuração para você conseguir enxergar os erros. A resposta do André diz que você tentou setar variaveis, mas na verdade são metodos, o sinal de `=` foi usado, deve seguir a documentação do phpmailer, tem lugares que são variaveis e tem locais que são metodos, me parece que este é o problema, sem querer ofender, me parece que você não entendeu o que são funções, classes e variaveis direito ainda. Estou enganado?

Comment: @MucaP você não colocou o erro lá na pergunta, desculpe mas já expliquei duas vezes. Espero que não me entenda mal, leia este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32622/discussion-between-mucap-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Pelo erro parece que você só postou parte do código, novamente peço que leia o link que lhe mandei e siga  as dicas, pois esta dificil ajudar com as informações atuais, pois este erro é um erro de digitação seu, mas com apenas parte do código não tem como descobrir aonde esta o erro, leia com atenção e siga as dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isso:

```
 $mail->setFrom = ('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com');
```

Devia ser isso:

```
 $mail->setFrom('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Parece que esta correto, note que `AddAddress =` deveria ser `AddAddress(...)`, mesma situação. +1

Answer (score 0):

Mucap, Isso vai acontecer mesmo se você usar um multiple no seu `input:file`

Se tiver mais de um arquivo, o tratamento vai ser diferente.

Provalmente, seu formulário está assim:

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" />
```

Altere para

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

Comment: Não, está igual ao que você disse que eu deveria fazer.